# excel macro : Change cell value dependant on original cell value

Tags: excel, vba

When recording a macro, i want to change the current value of a cell to a new value dependant on the original value. not set it to a "recorded" value.

Example : value in cell needs to change from .1234 (text) to 0,1234 (number). And
.56789 to 0,56789

My work method is:

```
record macro
"F2" : to change value,
"home" : go to beginning,
"del",
"del",
"0",
",",
"return",
stop record macro
```

but when i use the macro on other fields, the value is changed to 0,1234 even when original value is .5678 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in VBA but the most simple solution (if all your values begin with ".") is to use the built in "Text to Columns" Excel option (by simply selecting your entire column then ALT+A, +E, +F). If this has to be done with VBA please tell. Hope this alone helps.

**Edit** I've wrote this code to solve your problem (based on the rule of the cell values are starting with "." and then switching to numbers is made by adding a "0" to the initial text). Then "number" format is picked up by Excel as implicit format.

```
Sub ChangeFormat()
For i = 1 To 2 'This is the row index (it's now set to the 1st 2 rows.)
    For j = 1 To 2 'This is the column Index (i.e. column 2 is B, 1 is A, etc.) (it's now set to the A and B columns)
        If Left(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j), 1) = "." Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value = "0" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This needs to be automated. The end results will have multiple maps in wich i copy values (.0123) that needs to change. For now i can use your solution but it could be better.

Comment: ATM i can't really figure out how to use your solution. Because it is needed to be done in the same column, and your solution needs 2 columns

Comment: you must not break the text at all (specially based on the "." char), so you check delimited (not fixed width), then should keep the "tab" delimiter ticked (none other) and on column data format tick the "General". Also check that destination is the same column just below the general tick marks (usually this is implicit) and then Finish. The ALT+A, +E, +F uses the implicit option of the text to columns, and if you do not have any tabs in the columns' cells it won't populate any other column.